# Contrastive Learning for Segmentation

Tags: keras, pytorch, image-segmentation, self-supervised-learning

I'm trying to use Contrastive Learning or Self Supervised Learning to segment 2D medical images.

I want to use something like SimCLR or SimSiam, however, I'm getting stuck on how it should work (for example using [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/simsiam.py) code).

What should be my approach when training SimSiam with a U-Net like backbone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is the possible approach

approach 1: training a model with U-NET and doing the segmentations and predicting the medical diseases with the help of segmentation. This is a supervised approach.

approach 2:This is semi-supervised approach. Training a dataset with U-NET for contrastive learning. so you get meaningful features in your latent space and then you train your normal segmentation u-Net while using the pre-trained Encoder part of your contrastive learning U-Net. Here to remember this normal segmentation u-net would be different from the U-NET for contrastive learning. So, there would be 2 different classes for U-NET. and then simply do the predictions by the semantic segmentation approach.